# Why does this try-except print the wrong message?

Tags: python, io

Here's my code: (I just copied and pasted it.)

```
import sys

i = 0
files = ["untitled.kov", "coronavirus.py"]

def file_valid(filename):
    if filename[-4] == "." and filename[-3] == "k" and filename[-3] == "o" and filename[-1] == "v":
        return True

def create_file(file):
    try:
        if file[-4] == "." and file[-3] == "k" and file[-3] == "o" and file[-1] == "v":
            nf = open(file, "w")
    except:
        file = file + ".kov"
    finally:
        is_first_line = True
        while True:
            line = input("Line? (Type 'q' to quit.")
            if line == "q":
                nf.close()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                if is_first_line == False:
                    line = line + "\n"
                    nf.write(line)
                else:
                    nf.write(line)
                    is_first_line = False

i = 1
for file in files:
    print("Option " + str(i) + ": " + file)
    i = i + 1                                                                       
print("DISCLAIMER: Some files will not be in this list, but are avaliable.")
print("See this program's project folder to view a complete list of files.")

while True: 
    content = None

    filename = input("Which file would you like? (Type 'q' to quit.) ")

    try:       
        if file_valid(filename):
            f = open(filename, "r")
            content = f.read().splitlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Sorry, that file doesn't exist.")
        # if input("Create it? (y/n)") == "y":   - Not sure if this is valid..
            new_filename = input("What would you like the file to be called?")
            create_file(new_filename)                                                              
        else:
            print("Sure!")
            print("Remember, you can always add a file into the program folder!")
    except:
        if filename == "q":
           sys.exit()
        else:
            print("Sorry, something went wrong.")
    else:
        try:
            for line in content:
                i = i + 1
                print("Line " + str(i) + ": " + line)
            content.close()   
        except TypeError:
            print("Sorry, something went wrong.")
```

I'm trying to get it to say "Sorry, that file doesn't exist." (...) if it's a file with .kov extension, but it always just says "Sorry, something went wrong."

Also, in the "if input()... " part, is that valid code?
I would like to know if my code is overcomplicated, and how I could fix it.

Comment: Have you checked which `Sorry...` is being printed?

Comment: And to answer your second question, yes that's valid

Comment: You really need to stop using bare `except` clauses

Comment: @rdas - what do you mean?

Comment: You have two exactly same print statements. Check which one is being executed

Comment: I haven't read your code in detail, but one thing that jumps at me is that you are checking if both `file[-3] == "k" and file[-3] == "o"` are true at the same time. That can never be the case. I recommend reading the code very carefully and test individual pieces. (And since you're also asking for simplification hints, there are cleaner ways to check if the extension is what you expect. One is to split the string on a dot, e.g. `name, ext = filename.split(".")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! First, I deleted the first "Sorry, something went wrong." and it's parent `except` block. Then, I moved the quit check to the bottom `except TypeError` block. I also changed the `if file[-4] == "." and file[-3] == "k" and file[-3] == "o" and file[-1] == "v":` blocks to use `endswith()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for `open()`:

```
Open file and return a corresponding file object. If the file cannot be opened, an OSError is raised.
```

Replace `except FileNotFoundError:` with `except OSError:` and it will work.

By the way, you can check that the `filename` has .kov extension in the following way:

```
if filename.endswith(".kov"):
# your logic
```

Regarding the `if input()...` - it's valid.

Comment: What exactly? Did you try to change it? please share you full output...

Comment: except OSError:
        print("Sorry, that file doesn't exist.")
        if input("Create it? (y/n)") == "y":
            # Get new filename
            new_filename = input("What would you like the file to be called?")
            create_file(new_filename) @Gabip